# Precision of algorithm for Poisson regression (glm, R)

Tags: r, precision, glm, poisson

I want to do Poisson regression, but I need my regression function to run faster than `glm` and with at least as much precision.  Consider the following experiment:

```
## Here is some "data":
da = data.frame(matrix(c(0,1,212,1,0,200,1,1,27), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE))
names(da) = c("c1", "c2", "c")

## I want to do a Poisson regression of c on c1 and c2 and an intercept.

## Here is my function that uses optim for Poisson regression with the data da to find the intercept term:
zglm2 = function(precision = 1){  #predictors = best.terms, data = ddat, normalized = normalized
  # The design matrix
  M = as.matrix(cbind(rep(1, nrow(da)), da[,1:2]))
  # Initialize beta, the coefficients
  beta = rep(0, 3)
  # State the log-likelihood (up to a constant) for the data da and parameter beta:
  neg.pois.log.like.prop = function(beta){
    log.lambda = M%*%beta # log-expected cell counts under poisson model
    return(-sum(-exp(log.lambda) + da$c*log.lambda))}
  # State the gradient of the log-likelihood:
  grad.fun = function(beta){a = exp(M%*%beta)-da$c; return(t(a)%*%M)}
  # Estimate the MLE
  beta = optim(beta, neg.pois.log.like.prop, method = "BFGS", gr = grad.fun, control = list(reltol = precision*sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)))$par 
  return(beta[1])}

## Here are two ways of estimating the intercept term:
# Method 1
zglm2(precision = 1)
# Method 2
as.numeric(glm(c ~ 1+c1+c2, data = da, family = poisson)$coefficients[1])
```

My function, `zglm2` uses R's `optim` routine to find the maximum likelihood solution to the Poisson regression problem (for this special case).  `zglm2` takes an argument `precision`; values of this argument that are smaller than 1 make `optim` run beyond its default termination criteria to achieve greater precision.

Unfortunately, the results of Method 1 and Method 2 are too different (for my purposes);  7.358 versus 7.359.  Giving a smaller value, like 0.01, for the `precision` argument brings the two methods into reasonable agreement, leading me to suspect that R's `glm` function is very precise.

So here is my question:  what governs the level of precision in the result of `glm`?  Perhaps as a sub-question, what algorithm does `glm` use to find the maximum of the likelihood (I've dug into the source code but it's not easy for me).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty believing that "you have dug into the code" very deeply, since there is a a "control" parameter and a function that delivers argumetn to `glm`:

```
?glm
# control   
#        a list of parameters for controlling the fitting process. 
#        For glm.fit this is passed to glm.control.
```

Comment: Yes, I had looked at the `control` argument documentation but did not find it very helpful.  At any rate, I have become dissatisfied with my question and would like to remove it.